# Why excel formulas return zero when referencing two calculated cells from another table?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have two styled tables on different sheets, T1 (*having calculated values*), and T2 (*to calculate new values from calculated cells of T1*).

So in T2 I have writen this formula

```
='T1'!H58 - 'T1'!L58
```

The result it give me = 0

When
H58 = 213.84
&
L58 = 0.00

And I have no clue why of this behaviour.

PS: The same happens with this formula

```
=Table22910[@[Cant.]]-Table22910[@[Amort.]]
```

[Image of error in the Excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQJCp.png)

Comment: While using single cells or two even no need to use TABLE name as prefix, you may directly use Cell references. Like `A1+D20`, are from two Tables. generally Table name should be used when entire Column need to get Sum like, `=SUM(Table1[Sales])`.

Comment: @RajeshS Although I have tried your way it still gives me the same error. I think that my error has to do with the fact that I have used table formats

Comment: Better share sample data along with the Formula you have tried so far will help us to fix the issue!!

Comment: @RajeshS How can I upload the excel file here ?

Comment: Below the question you find link `EDIT` click it and form top find and Click `Image Icon` and follow `Browse` the `Add Picture`

Comment: Done, beware that T1 is making a reference to a similar table on another sheet

Comment: Done, and sent to your email

Answer (score 0):

*Enter this Formula in cell `I87` of `Sheet T1` and fill it down.*

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER([@[T. Inicio]]), ISNUMBER([@[T. Fin]])), ([@[T. Fin]] - [@[T. Inicio]] + 1), "")
```

**Note:** *No need to add Table name in Formula for the Columns, otherwise Excel considers whole column instead of a cell value.*